# What is benefits of encrypted Http Post Body?

Tags: http, encryption, request, http-post, public-key-encryption

I've just seen a bank application which encrypts Http Body Request even if it uses HTTPS. After that I've developed an application which encrypts Http Body Request via RSA. But I don't know what the benefits of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTTPS** only encrypts the data when in transit on the network. But both end points (the client and the server) would see/operate on the data in clear.

Encrypting the request data prior to sending using HTTPS, would protect the data until actively decrypted, and not just until received on the HTTP server.